# Stored Procedure in Orchard

Tags: sql, orchardcms

Hi We are working on a project and i am trying to call a stored procedure. I have searched for the solution but i didn't find any way that how to call a stored procedure so can any one please tell me how to execute stored procedure.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How ever finally i am using the below code to execute the stored procedure and get the result.

```
  using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
        {
            // temporary scope for new connection and setting stored procedure, parameters, and return RecordName list                               
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_settingsManager.LoadSettings().First().DataConnectionString))
            {
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    cn.Open();
                }
                const string storedProcedure = "usp_spName";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure, cn);  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsVerified", "value");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@page", "value"); 
                // for out put parameter
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalRows", 0);
                cmd.Parameters["@totalRows"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // To Get The Values of the result
                    int id=Convert.ToInt32(reader["Id"].ToString()); 
                }
                reader.Close();
                try
                {
                    // To Get the Out Put Perameter
                    totalRecords = (int)cmd.Parameters["@totalRows"].Value;
                }
                catch
                {
                    totalRecords = 0;
                }
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Dispose();
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, I don't know about stored procedures, but you can call stored functions using code like examaple below. I'm new to C# and orchard, so may be my approach is not correct and good enough. At first you should get `ISessionLocator` object instance, using `IOrchardServices`, then create NHibernate `ISession` instance  and then `IQuery/ISQLQuery` with `CreateSQLQuery()`.

here is example code of `Services` class

```
public class ExampleService {
    private readonly IOrchardServices _oServices;          

    public EParamsServices(IOrchardServices oServices) {
         _oServices = oServices;
    }

    public float GetRegionPopulationDencity(int rId){

        //resolve ISession locator (you can do this using dependencies in ctor)
        ISessionLocator sl = _oServices.WorkContext.Resolve<ISessionLocator>();             

        //create session
        ISession _session = sl.For(null);

        // create raw SQL query
        return _session.CreateSQLQuery(@"SELECT data.RegionDencity(:rId) as result")
                        .AddScalar("result", NHibernateUtil.Single)
                        .SetParameter<int>("rId", rId)
                        .List<float>()
                        .FirstOrDefault<float>();             
    }

}
```

I think you can exec stored procs the same way, just change SQL code do `exec yourProcName` and `ExecuteUpdate()`  instead of `List()` method (I'm not sure in this part)

you also should add reference to `NHibernate` assembly to your project and add `NHibernate` & `Orchard.Data` to your `using` part.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference **NHibernate** and **System.Data** in your module , then you can use the below code

```
var cmd =  _transactionManager.GetSession().Connection.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "MyStoredProcedure";

_transactionManager.GetSession().Transaction.Enlist(cmd);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```